# Every map $S^2$ $→$ $T$ induces the zero map on $H_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to show that every map $S^2$ $→$ $T$ induces the zero map on $H_2$.
Here $T$ denotes the torus.
I know that $H_2(S^2)= H_2(T)=\mathbb{Z}$ but other than that I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247613/is-there-a-continuous-function-from-the-torus-to-the-sphere-or-from-sphere-to-t/2247621#2247621)

Comment: How about using the long exact sequence of homotopy groups associated to a fibration? Or in a more elementary way the lifting property for maps with value in the base space of a covering.

Comment: @A.Rod That's an answer, and it shows more, namely that every map $S^2 \mapsto T$ is homotopic to a constant.

Comment: Shall I convert the comment into an answer? I mean there's not much more to say.

Comment: @A.Rod: Yes, you should write an answer along these lines.

Answer (score 8):

The point is that you have a covering map $p:\mathbb{R}^2\to T$ whose fiber is $\mathbb{Z}^2$ which is of course discrete.
Now if you take a map $f:\mathbb{S}^2\to T$ because our spaces are locally as nice as we want and because $\mathbb{S}^2$ is 1-connected you get a lifting of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (prescribed by choosing $t_0\in T$ and $s_0\in f^{-1}(t_0)$ and $x_0\in p^{-1}(t_0)$) that makes the following diagram commutes $$\begin{matrix} & & \mathbb{R}^2\\
 &\nearrow &\downarrow \\
\mathbb{S}^2 & \to & T\end{matrix}$$
This means that $H_2(\mathbb{S}^2,\mathbb{Z})\to H_2(T,\mathbb{Z})$ factors through $H_2(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{Z})=0$. Thus the map is $0$.

Incidently here's another way to see it, the fact that you have a fibration $p:\mathbb{R}^2\to T$ gives you a long exact sequence of homotopy groups (where I'm omitting base points)$$\pi_2(\mathbb{Z}^2)\to \pi_2(\mathbb{R}^2)\to \pi_2(T)\to \pi_1(\mathbb{Z}^2)\to \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$$
this tells you that $\pi_2(T)=0$ and thus every map from $\mathbb{S}^2 \to T$ is null-homotopic, in particular it will induce the zero map on all homology groups.