# No continuous injective function from 2-sphere to torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm currently working through a problem to show that there is no continuous injective function from the 2-sphere ($S^2$) to the torus ($T^2$). I saw a similar question posted here ([Is there a continuous function from the torus to the sphere? or from sphere to the torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247613/is-there-a-continuous-function-from-the-torus-to-the-sphere-or-from-sphere-to-t)) but I'm not yet acquainted with second homotopy groups. I suppose a contradiction can be reached somehow, but I'm not sure how to formulate it:

Suppose there exists such a continuous and injective function $f:S^2\rightarrow T^2$. $S^2$ is compact, so $f(S^2)\subset T^2$ must also be compact. $S^2$ is also simply connected while $\pi_1(T^2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, which I believe may come into play. I don't know where the injective property comes in however. Any guidance or hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try showing a continuous, injective function between two closed, connected manifolds is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I unfortunately haven't learned about manifolds yet either.

Comment: So what techniques are available to you?

Comment: @BarrettTravotsky Do you know that $S^2$ is not contractible?

Comment: @KeeleyHoek Yes.

Comment: Let $f : S^2 \to T^2$ be a continuous injective map. Then since $S^2$ is simply connected, $f$ is lifted to a map $F : S^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, which is injective since $f$ is. Then use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1519055/629362)

Comment: @BarrettTravotsky Out of interest how did you prove that $S^2$ is not contractible?

Comment: @BarrettTravotsky It fortunately doesn't come into play: unfortunately non-contractibility of $S^2$ requires a bit of technology (as far as I'm aware). But indeed $S^2$ is not contractible event though it is simply connected.

Comment: @BarrettTravotsky: A nice result to have: A continuous bijection between a Compact space and a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @ConnorMalin: Don't you need the map to be a bijection for f to be a homeomorphism?

Answer (score 2):

Any continuous and injective function $f : S^2 \to T^2$ would, since $S^2$ has trivial $\pi_1$, lift to a continuous and injective function $\widetilde{f} : S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ into the universal cover. Since $S^2$ is compact its image under $\widetilde{f}$ is compact, hence in particular closed. On the other hand $\widetilde{f}$ is injective, hence a local homeomorphism, which means it must have open image. In summary $\widetilde{f}(S^2)$ is clopen in $\mathbb{R}^2$, therefore is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But $\widetilde{f}$ has compact image, which is the desired contradiction.

---

As Arctic Char of course rightly emphasizes, the fact that $\widetilde{f}$ must be a local homeomorphism is "hard". This is an immediate consequence of the classical so-called "invariance of domain" theorem. I suppose given the traditional statement of invariance of domain we want to delete a pair of points $x_1$ and $x_2$ from $S^2$ and consider homoemorphisms $D^2 \to S^2 \setminus \{x_i\}$ with $D^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ the disk. Then post-composing these homeomorphisms with $\widetilde{f}$ we get that the image of each $D^2$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$: the image of $\widetilde{f}$ itself is then just the union of these two open sets, so again open.

Comment: But you really need to use invariance of domain I guess, to show that $\tilde f(S)$ is also open.

Comment: Yes I agree definitely this is needed (essentially equivalent) to get that $\widetilde{f}$ is a local homeomorphism.